# How to save form data when going to another page

Tags: html

I have a simple application form it is divided in 3 pages. What I want is when i fill up the 1st page, then when i go to another page the data is still there so I co go back to first page when I want to changes the data I inputted.

I tried saving it in session but I think that is not the right way to do it. any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, save them in sessions.

Comment: What server side technology you are using? Session is one way to store the data, javascript client side library object, local html storage can be used too. It all depends on your use case.

Comment: thanks. I will just go with the session. btw is there a possible way that i can name my session using a variable. for example session(variableHere)

Answer (score 2):

As you post the page, set the values you post in session variables
e.g.

```
<?php $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name']; ?>
```

Then in your input fields, check to see if the session is set & if so they display that.
e.g.

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php if (isset($_SESSION['name'])) { echo $_SESSION['name']; } " />
```

Make sure you start a session on each page you want to use them on!

```
<?php start_session; ?>
```

Comment: thanks. I will just go with the session. btw is there a possible way that i can name my session using a variable. for example session(variableHere) im using asp btw.

Comment: Yep:

First set your variable (this could in your case be a post variable i.e. $_POST['name'])
`$foo = 'bar';`

Then, set your session with this variable
`$_SESSION[$foo] = 'boom';`

You would then output that session either with `$_SESSION['bar'];` or `$_SESSION[$foo];`